# Should I change the URLs in the XML sitemap after 301 redirecting them?

Tags: redirects, url, 301-redirect, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am using 301 redirects for all URLs.  Should I change sitemap URLs now?

The sitemap currently contains the following URLs:

- `example.com/cat/1.html`
- `example.com/cat/2.html`
- `example.com/cat/3.html`

Should I change the sitemap's URLs to a new destination?

- `example.com/cat/year/1.html`
- `example.com/cat/year/2.html`
- `example.com/cat/year/3.html`

Comment: If the URLs in your sitemap redirect, Google will report that as an error.  See [Sitemap Error: some URLs redirect to other locations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81300/sitemap-error-some-urls-redirect-to-other-locations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, change them to the new URLs. Although the 301 redirects tell the search engines where to find moved pages you shouldn't be feeding them inaccurate information about your web pages. Besides possibly being error prone, it *may* also be an indicator of quality. While this may not affect your rankings, it *may* possibly affect crawl rate and other related things. If it is in your power to provide an accurate sitemap, you should do so.